# How to handle multiple output formats in a RESTful Zend Framework 2 application?

Tags: rest, zend-framework2, viewmodel, restful-architecture

I'm developing a RESTful application on Zend Framework 2 basis. Just implemented the `get(...)` method of the controller:

```
class SeminarsController extends RestfulController
{
    /**
     * @var Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway
     */
    private $seminarTable;

    ...

    public function get($id)
    {
        $seminarDetails = $this->getSeminarsTable()->findOnceByID($id)->current();
        return new JsonModel(array('data' => array(
            'id' => $seminarDetails->id,
            'title' => $seminarDetails->title,
            'details' => $seminarDetails->details
        )));
    }

    ...

}
```

Works fine. But now it's bound to a hard defined output format -- JSON. How can/should I make it more flexible, in order to enable the user/client to get the output in different formats?

---

EDIT

What I want to know is, what structure/architecture solution for such case(-s). I'm sure, there are best practices / standard solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a custom view strategy (you can create a custom view strategy to render any kind of response).

There is a great webinar on this by Matthew Weier O'Phinney that you can watch on [the Zend website](http://www.zend.com/en/webinar/Framework/70170000000c1Hw-RestfulZfApp-20130404.flv).

If the link doens't work, go to the [recorded webinars page](http://www.zend.com/en/resources/webinars/) and look for "Build RESTful ZF2 Applications".

The webinar contains all information you need including code samples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what I mean is more the architecture. I'll edit my question, in order to make it clear.